# Import external library to Angular 2 (Systemjs)

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/nepsilon/search-query-parser) in my Angular 2 project. I've tried:
`npm install search-query-parse --save`
And then:

1. `Adding via <script> in index.ts` - doesn't understand `export` in file (understandably)
2. Adding through RequireJS by adding it to the config file and then using `import { searchQuery} from 'search-query-parser';` - I can see the file is loaded through the network inspector, though I can't use it... I get `Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters`

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here is my system-config.ts (the relavant parts...)

```
map: {
  'search-query-parser': 'npm:search-query-parser'    
},
packages: {
  'search-query-parser': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

Comment: Where are you including your systemjs config? there should be an html file or similar where you have `<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>`, then `System.import('app')` or similar. If you're having troubles including loading it, you may always use: `System.set("search-query-parse", System.newModule(require('search-query-parse'));` before calling your system.import('app'). This will expose the module and you can access it in typescript using the regular ECMAScript6: `const sqp = require('search-query-parser');`.

Comment: @briosheje `const sqp = require('search-query-parser');` made it work! If you explain why in an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I need some further informations: did you change the configjs aswell adding System.set in your main or did you just use require? the problem may be related to the fact that search-query-parser exposes  a **parse** method, as you can see from there: https://github.com/nepsilon/search-query-parser/blob/master/lib/search-query-parser.js . Try this syntax instead: `import { parse } from 'search-query-parse'` and use it as `parse(query, options);`. Basically, the curly brackets `{` indicates that you are looking exactly for that variable (in your case searchQuery) which does not exists.

Comment: @briosheje I just used `require`, I also tried the method from your comment, that works too! I'll add my system-config.ts to the question... Thanks

Comment: There is yet another way that probably works aswell: `import * as searchQuery from 'search-query-parse'`, try it aswell (so you will use it as searchQuery.parse)

Comment: @briosheje that works too! Please put it in an answer so I can mark as correct.

Comment: I've put an answer below explaining with further details why each of the above solutions works, hope this will be useful in the future :) (remember to always check the source of the module if you feel confused or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It largely depends on the module itself in your case.

There are several ways to fix this, but the easiest one in this circumstance is using:

```
import * as searchQuery from 'search-query-parse'
```

This will fix the issue because it will import everything in the searchQuery constant, so you will use:

```
searchQuery.parse(params)
```

because the library exposes a **.parse** method.

Alternatively, you can also import the **parse method only**:

```
import { parse } from 'search-query-parse'
```

and use it as `parse(params)`

That is because the brackets notation (`{}`) will look **exactly** for the method / property exported by the module that exposes the name provided in the brackets.

If you still have no success with both methods, it's likely that the module is not being include at all by SystemJS (however, an error should be shown in that case).
There are several fixes for such an issue (where one of them is to search for a node or SystemJS module that actually is compliant with typescript), but the easiest one is looking for the HTML file where the systemjs config is included, locating the wrapper (`System.import(app)`) and, before such call, defining by yourself the module:

```
System.set("search-query-parse", System.newModule(require('search-query-parse'));
```

In this way, you're telling SystemJS that, at runtime, it needs to make the Node Module "search-query-parse" available under "search-query-parse", so using in typescript he vanilla-style require:

```
const sqp = require('search-query-parser');
```

Please note that there also are other ways to fix such an issue (usually through the systemjs file), however these likely are the easiest and portable ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically how you'd bring in an external script such that it's bundled and available to the app (assuming you are using the CLI): in angular-cli.json, note the "script" element. Try putting it there, it will then be bundled and the deps will (hopefully) resolve. I've done this for a number of different scripts, they always work.

```
"mobile": false,
    "styles": [
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
      "styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": ["./app/my_script.js"],
    "environments": {
      "source": "environments/environment.ts",
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
```

Wrote an article on that: http://www.tcoz.com/newtcoz/#/errata